# ls command not working in the home directory

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, ls, coreutils

The ls command works fine for me in all other directories except my home directory, where I get the following error:

* Exit with code 1, no result found, command line was:?? locate -b -i [\^g]*g[\^a]*a[\^r]*r[\^b]*b[\^a]*a[\^g]*g[\^e]*e[\^.]*\.[\^c]*c locate: illegal option -- b

I was passing --color as an option to ls in my .bash_profile, but I got rid of all color settings in .bashrc and .bash_profile assuming that the '--' in --color was the problem. I reinstalled the coreutils package as well, but no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `.` in your `$PATH`, and a file named `ls` in your home directory? (Tip: try `echo *` to list files when `ls` is broken.)

Comment: Also can you `cd` to somewhere else and then do `ls $HOME` from there? I’m wondering if the problem is what directory you’re in (your current working directory when running `ls`), or what directory you’re attempting to list.

Comment: What run string are you using? Check what `ls` runs by entering `type -a ls`, both in your home directory and in another where it works as expected.

Comment: @Spiff i do have a '.' in my $PATH variable. When I say echo $PATH, I see a '.' in Python.framework. Doing ls $HOME results in the same error.

Comment: @AFH type -a ls returns "ls is /bin/ls"

Comment: UPDATE: Even though 'ls' throws an error, it does list all my files including directories. I am able to pass other flags to ls as well BUT everything is listed in a single column regardless of my terminal window size - behavior that is not common when running ls in folders other than my home directory.

Comment: `ls` will choose a column width to suit the longest file name, so it needs only a single long file name of more than half the terminal width and everything will come out in a single column. I can't understand where the error message comes from, unless a previous error string was used as a file name, instead of being copied into a log file - if so, @Spiff's command `echo *` will show the same message.

Comment: @AFH echo * shows the same error message, and I do not have a file named 'ls' in my home directory.

Comment: I think that's the problem - you have a file of that name in your home directory, and its long name is enforcing the single column listing.

Comment: I am not able to see any file with the name 'ls' even though I am listing hidden files as well. The longest name in my home folder is that of a directory, and it has been there since a long time.

Comment: Do `ls >/dev/null; echo $?` -- what is the result? If the result is "0", then I suspect AFH is right. What if you do `ls | grep -v "Exit with code 1"`?

Comment: @glennjackman the result of the first command is 0. The output of the second command is: https://imgur.com/a/n7lLcLL

Comment: You have 2 files with strange names. To remove them: `rm -i ./*"Exit with code 1"* ./*"locate: illegal option"*` -- it may be one file with a newline in the name, hard to tell.

Comment: @glennjackman the response is no such file or directory. i will try renaming all files and folders in my home directory in an attempt to remove all newline characters.

Comment: UPDATE #2: Thank you all, I used ls -li to list all the files with their inode number and used 'find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;' to remove the file. I do not know which file I removed and am not able to gauge its importance, but it is what it is. ls is back to normal. Once again, thank you for all your time and support.